# Distance between input HTML

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put distance between two inputs, this is what it looks like now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRZ58.png. My code:

```
<form class="popup-form" id="login-popup-form">
<label>Your username/email:</label> <input class="popup-input" id="login-popup-username-field" name="username" placeholder="Username"/><br />
<label>Your password:</label> <input class="popup-input" id="login-popup-password-field" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
</form>
```

I tried this in CSS:

```
#popup-wrapper .popup-input
{
    position:absolute;
    right: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/66Vap/)

Comment: Your label elements either need to wrap the form controls or use the `for` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do:

```
margin-top: 15px;
```

Also you can use margin-bottom, margin-left and margin-right.

Or you could do:

```
.form-group {
    .input-class {
        padding: 5px;
    }
}
```